# Show views based on authentication

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have correctly implemented authentication on an MVC application I have been working on and would like some suggestions on the possibilty of showing different master layout pages for the different user roles.

My system currently has (and will probably always have) 3 user roles:

```
1. Administrator
2. Superior
3. General
```

What I would like to do is create 3 user layouts based on their role (after first being pointed to a login page) so _layout_admin.vbhtml etc

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? I have searched all over and know I can limit controllers but want to redirect them first to their correct user layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `~/Views/ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@Code
    Dim r = Roles.GetRolesForUser()
    If r.Contains("Administrator") Then
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutForAdmin.vbhtml"
    ElseIf r.Contains("Superior") Then
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutForSuperior.vbhtml"
    ElseIf r.Contains("General") Then
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutForGeneral.vbhtml"
    Else
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
    End If
End Code
```

Comment: Thanks. And if they are not logged in initially will they see the login page?

Comment: No, `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` will be used in this case. This will only switch the Layout based on the user role.

Comment: If I where to replace the final code there, _layout, with ~/Views/Account/Login.vbhtml, and the user then logs in would it run the ~/Views/ViewStart.vbhtml (ie is this run each and every time the view is changed?) or does it only run the first time?

Comment: `_ViewStart` runs always, on every Razor view. So if the user is not logged in, `~/Views/Account/Login.vbhtml` will be used and once he logs in, depending on the roles he belongs to, the corresponding Layout will be used. And this for every single page he requests.

Comment: Makes sense. So I will always force them to go to the login page. Thanks

Comment: @NParks, just to clarify: _ViewStart.vbhtml will not run when you `return PartialView()` from a controller, only when you `return View()`. So it doesn't run always on every Razor view, just the ones that are not designated as partial when returning from the controller.